# Get the desired table from the site

Tags: python, html, python-requests

There is a [link](http://uiiit.donnuet.ru/raspisanie/index.php) to a site with a schedule. On the page there are 3 elements `<select>`: *Institute (faculty), course, group*. How to get the desired table through Requests? I tried Post and Get, unsuccessfully.

```
import requests

data = {
    "table11": "597",
    "crs": "2",
    "table2": "2973",
    "name" : "СРВ-21-А"
}
res = requests.get("http://uiiit.donnuet.ru/raspisanie/index.php", data=data)
```

Maybe Requests will not help here at all, and it is better to try Selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup to parse the elements:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = {
    "table11": "597",
    "crs": "2",
    "table2": "2973",
    "name" : "СРВ-21-А"
}
res = requests.get("http://uiiit.donnuet.ru/raspisanie/index.php", data=data)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')  # parse the response text
table = soup.find('table')  # get the table
table_body = table.find('tbody')  # get the table body
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')  # get all table rows

data = []
for row in rows:  # loop over every row
    cols = row.find_all('td')  # find every column in this row
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]  # get the text in every column
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])  # append it to the data list
```

Unfortunately I dont speak russian.

To get the table it seems like you have to request

```
http://uiiit.donnuet.ru/raspisanie/tablemain.php
```

providing data for an field named `id` and one named `names`

Comment: Where did you get this link?  `/tablemain.php`

Comment: If you go to http://uiiit.donnuet.ru/raspisanie/index.php do rightclick->inspect and then choose network in the dev-tools. There you can see every request that gets send. When you choose values from the dropdown, you can see that one is send to /tablemain.php to retrieve the table information.